# Regexp for European price

Tags: javascript, regex

I tested the following regexp for US prices (delimiter comma, separator dot) which is running fine:

```
 ^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:,?[0-9]{3}){0,3}(\.[0-9]{2})?$
```

It works, prices like 30,000.000 are refused. Only 2 decimals are accepted.

I tried to exchange them for handling European prices:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:.?[0-9]{3}){0,3}(\,[0-9]{2})?$
```

but it does not work, prices like 30.000,000 are accepted, which is wrong. Only 2 decimals should be accepted.

What's wrong in these 2 regexps?

Comment: F.J's answer is correct. Just a side, the first regex for US would allow for a value like this: `900,000000,000.00` that is Nine-hundred-million-thousand dollars. Probably correct, but sounds kind of funny. If a comma is included, you could force it to be used every 3rd decimal, or optionally accept all digits using this: `^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:(?:,[0-9]{3}){1,3}|[0-9]{1,9})?(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In regex, `.` is a special character so when you want to match a literal dot you need to escape it with a backslash (`\.`).  This is not the case for commas, so you can leave them unchanged.

In your attempt you switched the `,` and the `.` which left you with an unescaped `.` and a `\,` at the end, when you actually want to switch the `,` and the `\.` like this:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:\.?[0-9]{3}){0,3}(,[0-9]{2})?$
```